# how to deserialize datetime in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am sending list of date time from my c# code to javascript.
In javascript I am getting date as

```
/Date(1331836200000)/,/Date(1331987200000)/
```

How do i convert it in date in javascript.

Comment: You don't have quotes ? How are you really receiving it ? Is that a text file ?

Comment: I don't understand this notation `/` is used for Regular Experssions. Are you getting it as a string, or a number?

Comment: Sharepoint also serializes like this

Comment: Are you sending it as a CSV format?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Supposing you have this string :

```
var str = "/Date(1331836200000)/,/Date(1331987200000)/";
```

then you may get an array of dates by using

```
var dates = str.match(/\d+/g).map(function(s){ return new Date(+s) });
```

Comment: The "dates" variable will hold an array of strings; to get actual Date instances you'll have to call the Date constructor (`new Date`) with those strings as an argument.

Comment: @maerics right. Fixed. I always forget that the Date function when not used as a constructor returns a string...

Answer (score 0):

You would be after a function like this

```
function parseDate(datestring) {
  var len;
  if (datestring && (len = datestring.length)) {
    return new Date(+datestring.substring(6,len-2));
  }
  return null;
}
```

datestring should be `"/Date(milliseconds)/"`

I use something like this for processing dates from SharePoint